# Renamed a few classes VIA Refractor and now my SQL Queries are not working

Tags: java, android, dao

I was renaming a few of my classes to try and fit the Java naming convention, but when I renamed my Entities the queries I had stopped working and started giving me an error (Below)

I tried renaming it back, but that did work either. Let me know if I am missing any information.

Error message 1 -

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type 
(java.util.List<com.example.c196_studentapp.Entity.assessmentEntity>)
```

Error Message 2 -

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or 
missing database (no such table: assessmentEntity)
```

assessmentEntity class -

```
package com.example.c196_studentapp.Entity;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "assessment_table")
public class assessmentEntity {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

private int assessmentID;
private String assessmentName;
private String assessmentType;
private String endDate;

public assessmentEntity(int assessmentID, String assessmentName, String assessmentType, String endDate, int courseID) {
    this.assessmentID = assessmentID;
    this.assessmentName = assessmentName;
    this.assessmentType = assessmentType;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.courseID = courseID;
}

public int getAssessmentID() {

    return assessmentID;
}

public void setAssessmentID(int assessmentID) {

    this.assessmentID = assessmentID;
}

public String getAssessmentName() {

    return assessmentName;
}

public void setAssessmentName(String assessmentName) {

    this.assessmentName = assessmentName;
}

public String getAssessmentType() {

    return assessmentType;
}

public void setAssessmentType(String assessmentType) {

    this.assessmentType = assessmentType;
}

public int getCourseID() {

    return courseID;
}

public void setCourseID(int courseID) {

    this.courseID = courseID;
}

private int courseID;

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {

    this.endDate = endDate;
} 
  }
```

assessmentDAO class -

```
package com.example.c196_studentapp.DAO;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import com.example.c196_studentapp.Entity.assessmentEntity;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface assessmentDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    public void insert(assessmentEntity assessment);

    @Update
    public void update(assessmentEntity assessment);

    @Delete
    public void delete(assessmentEntity assessment);

    @Query("DELETE FROM assessmentEntity")
    public void deleteAllAssessments();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM assessmentEntity ORDER BY assessmentID ASC")
    List<assessmentEntity> getAllAssessments();



     }
```

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in your question, not an image.

Comment: Sorry about that. I took the screenshot out and posted the error in my text.

Answer (score 0):

According to this :

```
@Entity(tableName = "assessment_table")
```

your table name is `assessment_table`

In your query, you should use `assessment_table` instead of `assessmentEntity`:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM assessment_table")
public void deleteAllAssessments();

@Query("SELECT * FROM assessment_table ORDER BY assessmentID ASC")
List<assessmentEntity> getAllAssessments();
```